# How to print lots of Envelopes

Tags: printer, envelope-printer

How to print lots of Envelopes.

- I wish to print onto **lots** of **envelopes**:
- A few thousand as a one of task (may repeat each year)
- Good quality **colour photo**
- The colour photo is different on each envelope
- and graphics that has **solid colour** (plus some **black text**)
- Be painless to operate, I don’t wish to have to clear jams often
- As I need to put the envelopes into batches, I don’t need an input try that will take hundreds of envelopes.
- I also need to get a new colour printer to print normal A4 paper; this may or may not be the same printer.
- I live in the UK, if you care.

What should I be looking at?

Comment: If its a one off, with a lot of quantity, you might want to look at getting it professionally done, and just printing the address on yourself, IMO

Comment: @The Journeyman Geek,  Thanks, however, the colour photo is different on each envelope.  Otherwise getting the envelopes (maybe with windows) preprinted would be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HP CP3525x Colour Laserjet Printer](http://www.oyyy.co.uk/product.php/73631/hp-cp3525x-colour-laserjet-printer-a4-30ppm-1200-x-600-usb-duplex--network-ready--additional-500-sheet-tray?utm_source=google&utm_medium=base&utm_campaign=products)

> This HP printer is designed to maximize your investment. With the HP Color LaserJet CP3520 Printer, you can get black prints for the same cost as on a black-and-white HP LaserJet2—providing general office effectiveness, while also allowing you to print in colour! Choose an optional high-capacity print cartridge for even more value. With HP’s Color Access Control technology, easily control who can print in colour and how much. Effortlessly share the printer with embedded gigabit networking. Enjoy enterprise-class security features such as IPSec and IPv6. With expandable memory, an open EIO slot, and optional third party solutions, you can expand printer capabilities as your business needs grow. Produce professional, attention-grabbing marketing materials in your own office by combining HP ColorSphere toner with HP’s full line of papers. Easily produce brochures, flyers, postcards and newsletters on up to 58 lb glossy media. Effectively communicate internally and generate sales for less time and money than the cost of outsourcing.

Comment: thanks, how well does it cope with envelopes, in the past I have found that most printers that claim to cope with envelopes, just jam etc if you do many envelopes.

Comment: i've managed 500 at a time, no jams

Answer (score 0):

Not a cheep opiton but the [Kyocera Mita FS-C5025](http://www.trustedreviews.com/printers/review/2007/05/13/Kyocera-Mita-FS-C5025N/p3)N has low running costs and a optional envelope feeder, however I don't know how well it does photos.